# Cannot modify deposit using interop.qbfc12

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

In a c# program using interop.qbfc12, the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
<DepositModRq requestID = "0">
<DepositMod>
<TxnID>B2864-1388784731</TxnID>
<EditSequence>1388784731</EditSequence>
<TxnDate>2014-01-03</TxnDate>
<DepositToAccountRef>
<FullName>Checking Acct-CCFCSB</FullName>
</DepositToAccountRef>
<Memo>Test deposit memo for 01032014-1</Memo>
<DepositLineMod>
<TxnLineID>B2866-1388784731</TxnLineID>
</DepositLineMod>
<DepositLineMod>
<TxnLineID>B2867-1388784731</TxnLineID>
</DepositLineMod>
</DepositMod>
</DepositModRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

produces this error:

```
DepositMod

DepositLineModList:

element(1) - ORDepositLineMod: required field is missing

End of DepositLineModList

End of DepositMod
```

When I use the same code in a vba project using qbfc12 type library, I get no error.

Does the interop library differ from the qbfc library?  What must I do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look at the XML being generated by the QBFC12 library to see what the difference is.

You are giving DepositLineMod's, but what are you modifying?